# How to get uploaded filepath in Guzzlehttp?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am going to upload file with `Guzzlehttp` following this code:

```
$client->request('POST', '/post', [
  'multipart' => [
   [
      'name'     => 'baz',
      'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r')
   ]
]);
```

Where I am going to get path with this code:

```
$data['thumb']->getPathName()
```

It is giving me like this: `"/tmp/phpTSAE8d"`

How will I process this to pass another `api` which will process this image to do the rest of the work?

Comment: uploaded path will always go to "default temporary/upload directory of your PHP setting". In ALL of upload tutorials I've come across, they always teach to "move uploaded file to actual/proper directory". Therefore, if you want your file to be used later, you need to also move it outside of temporarty directory

Comment: I am getting a file object. Is it possible to pass this object via guzzle?

Comment: use is_file() to check for file in object and then pass it to contents key in multipart, is it showing any errors?

Comment: Giving me null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest Laravel version on your application. You can use the [HTTP CLIENT](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client). It is also running guzzle but easier to debug.

To pass an file using HTTP you can do like this:

```php
$response = Http::attach(
    'attachment', file_get_contents('photo.jpg'), 'photo.jpg'
)->post('http://example.com/attachments');
```

or

```php
$photo = fopen('photo.jpg', 'r');

$response = Http::attach(
    'attachment', $photo, 'photo.jpg'
)->post('http://example.com/attachments');
```

Here's the link on the documentation [multi-part-request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#multi-part-requests).

Hope this will help you on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am using 5.2 version to upload that file and going to pass in Laravel 8 version to process that file.

Comment: this method only works for Laravel `7.x` or later. Maybe you can check the documentation to see some similarities. or  check the source code on how they handle HTTP CLIENT in the back maybe you'll see some tricks/methods

Answer (score 0):

Try to use file_get_contents

```
'multipart' => [
    [
        'name'     => 'FileContents',
        'contents' => file_get_contents('/path/to/file')
    ]
```